# JWT 'DecodeResult' does not have a member named 'Success'

Tags: ios, swift, jwt

Im trying to use the [Swift JWT pod](https://github.com/kylef/JSONWebToken.swift) to decode a `JWT` Token.

```
// Get and decode the response
    var response = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>(), error: NSErrorPointer())
    let responseContent = NSString(data:response!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let decoded = JWT.decode(responseContent! as String, .HS256(secret))

    println(decoded.Success)
```

This code gives an error:

```
'DecodeResult' does not have a member named 'Success'
```

It looks like DecodedResult has an `Enum`: https://github.com/kylef/JSONWebToken.swift/blob/master/JWT/Decode.swift#L50

How can I go about accessing the payload in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a switch to extract the associated values of the enum.

```
switch decoded {
case .Success(let header, let payload, let signature, let signatureInput):
    // do something with the values
case .Failure(let invalidToken):
    // handle the failure
}
```